# Intepreting results of Granger Causality test on a sparseVAR

Tags: r, p-value, regularization, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I want to run a Granger Causaity test on a pair of time series using the R library sparsevar embedded within python code (I am using rpy2). I am building a VAR model with fitVAR() with two time series with a p (lag) of 6. I then run the testGranger() function on the VAR model and it returns matrices for each lag. I thought this would be the p-values but some of the values are negative. I thought it might be the test statistic or a correlation coefficient, but it's strange that there isn't a p-value. The result object does not have any attributes.

testGranger source code: https://github.com/svazzole/sparsevar/blob/master/R/utilsVAR.R

impulseResponse and errorBandsIRF source code: https://github.com/svazzole/sparsevar/blob/master/R/impulseResponse.R

original documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparsevar/sparsevar.pdf

Apologies in the advance; the result was printed weirdly on my console.

```
robjects.globalenv['sparsevar'] = robjects.r('fitVAR(endog, p=6)')
robjects.r('irf <- impulseResponse(sparsevar)')
robjects.r('eb <- errorBandsIRF(sparsevar, irf, verbose=FALSE)')
robjects.r('result <- testGranger(sparsevar, eb)')

robjects.r('print(result)')

[[1]]

  
        AR
       BR

AR
 0.2940856
 0.000000

BR
 0.0000000
 1.065469




[[2]]

  
        AR
         BR

AR
 0.1855526
  0.0000000

BR
 0.0000000
 -0.1814012




[[3]]

  
 AR
 BR

AR
  0
  0

BR
  0
  0




[[4]]

  
 AR
            BR

AR
  0
  0.000000e+00

BR
  0
 -9.916103e-05




[[5]]

  
 AR
 BR

AR
  0
  0

BR
  0
  0




[[6]]

  
 AR
        BR

AR
  0
 0.0000000

BR
  0
 0.8173568
```

Comment: Obtaining p-values for regularized regression can be very tricky. It would not suprise me at all if the package did not provide p-values.

Comment: @RichardHardy ah, right. I wasn't aware of that.